# How do I make my bot reply with what the user sent?

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a giveaway bot and I cant get my bot to put what the user said into a field. For example, the bot says, "what do you want to giveaway?" then the user replies with something then the bot puts that "something" into its next reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take this simple bot

```
import discord
from bot import search_result, get_recent_query


class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
    """
    showing message on console when the server start
    :return:
    """
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):

        # event listener, where sending message is a event

        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author == client.user:
        return

        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

    # checking the conditions, with which the user input starts
    # if user input is hi, return hey
        if message.content.startswith('hi'):
            msg = 'hey {0.author.mention} '.format(message)
            await message.channel.send(msg)
```

get the user reply from `async def on_message(self, message)`  here message is what user reply and send the processed data to user as `await message.channel.send(new_msg)`